# Define a struct which is derived from true_type whenever a given SFINAE-able constructor would be taken

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, type-traits

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<typename T, class Tuple>
class vector
{
    using size_type = typename Tuple::size_type;

    template<typename... Elements,
        typename = decltype(std::declval<Tuple>().reserve(size_type()))>
        typename = decltype(std::declval<Tuple>().push_back(T())),
    vector(Elements&&... elements)
    { /* ... */ }
};
```

I want to define a nested struct `supports_reserve_push_back` which is derived from `std::true_type` whenever the constructor above would be enabled (and which is derived from `std::false_type` in the other case).

How can I do this?

Comment: If it's the only c'tor, the old overload resultion with a varargs method may do it.

Comment: @StoryTeller No, there are more constructors. Especially, there is another constructor with the same signature.

Comment: Well, the obvious solution would than be to duplicate the checks which enable the c'tor.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't know how I need to define the struct. Could you provide an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I've modified the code to make it [build](http://ideone.com/uNjrId). And implemented the trait you requested, to the best of my understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <map> 

namespace example {

template<typename...>
using void_t = void;

template<typename T, class Tuple>
struct vector {
    using size_type = typename Tuple::size_type;
    using tuple_type = Tuple;
    using elem_type = T;

    template<typename... Elements>
    vector(Elements&&... elements)
    { /* ... */ }
};

template <class T, typename = void>
struct supports_reserve_push_back : std::false_type {};

template <class Vec> 
struct supports_reserve_push_back<Vec, void_t<
  decltype(std::declval<typename Vec::tuple_type>().reserve(typename Vec::size_type())),
  decltype(std::declval<typename Vec::tuple_type>().push_back(typename Vec::elem_type())) >
>
  : std::true_type {};

}

int main() {
    std::cout
    << example::supports_reserve_push_back<example::vector<int, std::vector<int>>>::value
    << '\n'
    << example::supports_reserve_push_back<example::vector<int, std::map<int, int>>>::value;
    return 0;
}
```

A few thing to note:

1. The way you wrote the c'tor originally caused a hard error when instantiating the class in the negative case. That's why I removed the chcck from the c'tor.
2. I'd suggest you define the type traits first, and use them to enable your c'tors.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename AlwaysVoid, template <typename...> class Operation, typename... Args>
struct detect_impl : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Operation, typename... Args>
struct detect_impl<void_t<Operation<Args...>>, Operation, Args...> : std::true_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Operation, typename... Args>
using detect = detect_impl<void_t<>, Operation, Args...>;

template <typename T, typename Sz>
using has_reserve = decltype(std::declval<T>().reserve(std::declval<Sz>()));

template <typename T, typename U>
using has_push_back = decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back(std::declval<U>()));

template <typename Tuple, typename T, typename size_type>
constexpr bool supports_reserve_push_back = detect<has_reserve, Tuple, size_type>{} && detect<has_push_back, Tuple, T>{};
```

Test:

```
template <typename T, class Tuple>
class vector
{
public:
    using size_type = typename Tuple::size_type;

    template <typename... Elements, typename U = Tuple,
    std::enable_if_t<supports_reserve_push_back<U&, T, size_type>, int> = 0>
    vector(Elements&&... elements)
    {
    }

    template <typename... Elements, typename U = Tuple,
    std::enable_if_t<!supports_reserve_push_back<U&, T, size_type>, int> = 0>
    vector(Elements&&... elements)
    {
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51a192fd0fe0739f)

Comment: What's the reason to use `std::declval<T&>` instead of `std::declval<T>` in `has_push_back`? And why are you using `std::declval<U>()` instead of `U()`? Suppose a class `T` has a `push_back` method for some argument type `U`. Let's assume `U = foo` for some class `foo`. Will `has_push_back` evaluate to true even when we replace `foo` by `foo&&`? And how can I ensure that the `push_back` method of `T` accepts a rvalue?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, using `U()` explicitly places the demand on a class to be default constructable. This is unreasonable since many useful classes cannot be made so. That's the whole reason `std::declval` was added.

Comment: @StoryTeller And what's the reason to use `std::declval<T&>` instead of `std::declval<T>`?

Comment: @0xbadf00d the former yields an lvalue

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki The return type of `std::declval<T>` is `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>`. Since `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T&>` is `T&` and `std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>` is `T&&`, if `T` is not a cv- or ref-qualified type, I don't know why you say that *the former yields an lvalue* (The former should yield an lvalue **reference**, shouldn't it?). But why is that crucial here? What's the benefit, if we use `std::declval<T&>` instead of `std::declval<T>`?

Comment: @0xbadf00d do you usually say `std::vector<int>{}.push_back(1);` **or** `v.push_back(1);` ? if a member function is ref-qualified, it does matter. also, an rvalue reference could be an lvalue, that depends on a context it is used in, I used word *lvalue* on purpose, a function call declaring an lvalue reference type as its return type is an lvalue expression

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, that makes sense to me. But what about `U`? How can I check that `push_back` accepts an rvalue reference?

Comment: @0xbadf00d `std::declval<U>()` yields an rvalue

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Please take a look at an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f3d1bcbac87891c). I want the output to be `false`, cause `tuple<T>::push_back` has argument type `T`, but I want to verify that the argument type is `T&&`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d a new `double` is constructible from an rvalue expression of type `double`, then why it should fail ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Cause I want to ensure that `push_back` is not of the form `push_back(T)`. In that case a call of `push_back` would involve copying `T` and the intend of my constructor is to fill the `vector` by a sequence of arguments without creating any copies.

Comment: @0xbadf00d then you'd need to check the signature of `push_back`; there are plenty of solutions on SO already

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace details{
  template<template<class...>class Z,class,class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z,class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z,std::void_t<Z<Ts...>,Ts...>:
  std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z,class... Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
```

Wrap up your decltypes into template usings and do some `&&` and done.

There is also a std experimental similar to above.

```
template<class T, class U>
using push_back_r = decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back(std::declval<U>()));
template<class T>
using reserve_r = decltype(std::declval<T>().reserve(1));

template<class T, class U>
constexpr can_apply<push_back_r,T,U> has_push_back={};
template<class T>
constexpr can_apply<reserve_r,T> has_reserve={};

template<bool b>using bool_t=std::integral_constant<bool,b>;

template<class T,class U>
constexpr bool_t<has_push_back<T,U>&&has_reserve<T>>
efficiently_fillable_with = {};
```

Then `efficiently_fillable_with<T,U>` is true type iff you can reserve space with T and then push Us into it.  The r/l value category of `T` and `U` is preserved: if you want to know about filling an non-cinstant lvalue of `T` with rvalue `U`s:

```
efficiently_fillable_with<T&,U>
```

If you want to fill with `U const&` instead of rvalues, pass `U const&`.

Comment: I assume the usage would be `template<class T, typename U>
using has_push_back = decltype(std::declval<T&>().push_back(std::declval<U>()));` and `template<typename T, class Tuple>
constexpr bool tuple_has_reserve_v = type_traits::can_apply<has_push_back, Tuple, T>{};`, right? How can I check, if the `push_back` method accepts a rvalue (instead of a lvalue or a const reference)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Remove `&`s from your usings, pass `&`s in to describe r/l value-ness of parameters.

Comment: Please be specific. What do I need to change in `has_push_back`?

Comment: @0xbad What you wrote tells you if it will accept an rvalue.  If you want to exclude non-const reference from passing, do a test passing `U&`, making two traits X (taking U) and Y (taking U&), then do `X and not Y`, but I suspect I misunderstood your request as it seems nonsensical.  Why would you care if it accepts an rvalue, but also care that it rejects non-constant lvalues?  /shrug.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed a word: I want to check, if `push_back` accepts an rvalue **reference**. The reason is the following: `Tuple` might be `std::vector<T>`. If I would not care, I could simply use `template<typename Elements...> vector(Elements&&... elements) : m_elements{ static_cast<T>(std::forward<Elements>(elements))... } {}`. The problem with that is that `m_elements{ static_cast<T>(std::forward<Elements>(elements))... }` will invoke the `std::initializer_list`-constructor of `std::vector` and thereby creating copies of the `elements` instead of moving them.

Comment: That's the reason why I want to use a `reserve` and `push_back` combination. But this only makes sense, when `push_back` accepts an rvalue reference. Otherwise we would still make copies of the `elements`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following approach:

Have your `vector` template class inherit from a superclass, like this:

```
template<typename T, class Tuple> class vector
   : public supports_reserve_push_back_impl<
       vector_has_default_constructor<T, Tuple>::value() > {

// ...

}
```

Now, define a `vector_has_default_constructor` template class that takes the same template parameters:

```
template<typename T, class Tuple> class vector_has_default_constructor {

public:
// ...

};
```

In `vector_has_default_constructor`:

- Define a `constexpr bool value()` method with the same exact signature as the vector's constructor. This `constexpr` method returns true.
- Define an overload `constexpr bool value()` with a `...` signature, which should have lower priority in the overload resolution. This `constexpr` returns false.

Now, this situation is reduced to defining two trivial specializations, `supports_reserve_push_back_impl<true>` and `supports_reserve_push_back_impl<false>`.

`supports_reserve_push_back_impl<true>` contains your desired `supports_reserve_push_back` value, and is inherited by your `vector`.

`supports_reserve_push_back_impl<false>` is empty.